# How to catch enter key and change event to space key

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

As I know I can't just change and return another `e.keyCode` when I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> into "input" tag. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input:text').keypress(function(e) {
    var KeyID = e.keyCode;
    switch(KeyID)
    {
        case 32:
            alert("Space");
            break;
        case 13:
            alert("Enter");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
})
```

Event properties are all READ-only. You cannot change one keyCode to another. Depending on what you want to do you can change the event manually like this using jquery:

```js
    $('input:text').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13)
            this.value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(32)
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="fname">
```